# Cannot resolve method 'findViewById(int)' in my firebase service

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

i have this problem in my service that i created on Android Studio.

[image]

I created a new Service,it is a **.java** file and i can't use findViewById inside this service.I think i must reference the MainActivity somehow inside there,i don't know how to do that and i want some help.Sorry if i have some mistakes but i am a begginer on Android Developing.
Thank you.

**This is the code from the service that i made**

```
package com.example.qkiri.buttonnum;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

import static android.content.ContentValues.TAG;


public class MessageRec extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    public MessageRec(MainActivity mainActivity) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

        int number;
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

        number = 23;
        final TextView txtView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.service);
        txtView2.setText(number);

        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
        }

        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + 
            remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Even if you used the activity instance, it still might not be able to find the layout.. Implementing a BroadcastReceiver on the Activity  is the correct way to update the UI

Comment: wrong use if service buddy. follow what cricket is suggesting.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to make ui changes in Service, you have to develop communication parts in the project.
You can develop communication parts let the Activity know the UI changing request from Service.

There are several ways to implement this. You can use one of Broadcast, Binder and Message.

Please check in more detail with following url:
http://developer.samsung.com/galaxy/others/effective-communication-between-service-and-activity

Answer (score 0):

You should not update UI from service but from activity, but if you really need to then you need to do 1 step before trying to call method findViewById():

1) get inflater reference:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

2) Now, use the reference to call findViewById method:

```
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.myLayout, null);

final TextView txtView2 = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.service);
```

Comment: I did that but i have an error at "layout.findViewById(R.id.service)",and the error is "Method findViewById must be called from the UI thread, currently inferred thread is worker"